# Android Как правильно реализовать PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, mvp, moxy

Делаю приложение - расписание. Использую MVP + Moxy

Необходимо сделать фрагмент с выбором параметров расписания

Расписание бывает 3 видов: на неделю, на семестр, на определенную дату.
У всех них имеется общее: выбор группы студентов

Я решил сделать фрагмент, где находится spinner с выбором группы.

Выбор параметров, зависящих от типа расписания, решил размещать в ViewPager.

Вопрос: Мне нужно отдельно создавать View, Presenter к каждому типу расписанию, находящихся в ViewPager. Если нет и можно все это реализовать в одном View и Presenter, то как мне получить доступ к элементам, находившихся в ViewPager?

Текущий скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главный Фрагмент:

```
public class SearchScheduleStudentFragment extends PresenterFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, SearchScheduleStudentView {
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private SearchScheduleStudentsPagerAdapter mSearchScheduleStudentsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private AppCompatSpinner mSpinner;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @InjectPresenter
    SearchScheduleStudentPresenter mPresenter;

    @ProvidePresenter
    SearchScheduleStudentPresenter providePresenter() {
        return new SearchScheduleStudentPresenter(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected SearchScheduleStudentPresenter getPresenter() {
        return mPresenter;
    }

    public static SearchScheduleStudentFragment newInstance() {
        return new SearchScheduleStudentFragment();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_search_schedule_students, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refresher);
        mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.search_student_schedule_pager);
        mSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_student_groups);

        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSearchScheduleStudentsPagerAdapter = new SearchScheduleStudentsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSearchScheduleStudentsPagerAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mPresenter.getGroups();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    }




    @Override
    public void showLoading() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hideLoading() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void showError() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        mPresenter = null;
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void showSemesters(List<Semester> semesters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void showGroups(List<GroupStudents> groupsStudents) {
        List<String> groupsName = new ArrayList<>();
        for (GroupStudents groupStudents : groupsStudents) {
            groupsName.add(groupStudents.getName());
            Log.d("Группа", groupStudents.getName());
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, groupsName);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Его View и Presenter

```
@InjectViewState
public class SearchScheduleStudentPresenter extends BasePresenter<SearchScheduleStudentView> {

    private SearchScheduleStudentView mView;

    public SearchScheduleStudentPresenter(SearchScheduleStudentView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    public void getSemesters(){
        mCompositeDisposable.add(
                ApiUtils.getApi()
                .getSemesters()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        response -> mView.showSemesters(response)
                )
        );


    }

    public void getGroups(){
        mCompositeDisposable.add(
                ApiUtils.getApi()
                .getGroups()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        response -> mView.showGroups(response)
                )
        );
    }


    //Относится не к главному, а к pagerAdapter
    public void getWeeks(){
        mCompositeDisposable.add(
                ApiUtils.getApi()
                        .getWeeks()
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                response -> mView.showWeeks(response)
                        )
        );
    }
}



public interface SearchScheduleStudentView extends BaseView {

    void showSemesters(List<Semester> semesters);

    void showGroups(List<GroupStudents> groupStudents);

    void showWeeks(List<Week> weeks);

}
```

PagerAdapter

```
public class SearchScheduleStudentsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int COUNT_FRAGMENT = 2;

    public SearchScheduleStudentsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return SearchScheduleWeekStudentsFragment.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return SearchScheduleDayStudentsFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return COUNT_FRAGMENT;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return "На неделю";
            case 1:
                return "На дату";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я думаю что не нужно, ведь данные все более менее однотипны и являются частью дру гдруга. А вот ViewPager реализовать с одним адаптером принимающем разные вьюхи: https://ziginsider.github.io/Multiple_Row_Types_In_Recyclerview/ И тогда не нужно разделять всё это на фрагменты, а получится достаточно аккуратно в трёх карточках.

Comment: @Valeriy Я что-то не понял, что вы мне хотели сказать, в вашем примере расписывается о recyclerview, а у меня обычные фрагменты

Comment: @danishlik, не совсем понял вас. Я имел ввиду что реализовать не три фрагмента которые вы покладёте во ViewPager, А использовать ViewPager который будет принимать на вход три варианта карточек, которые будут занимать большую часть экрана в которой и будет выводиться расписание. Спиннер груп ложим в активити, немного выше ViewPager. К этому активити привязываем Presenter и запрашиваем данные из репозитория. P.S. Я только обратил внимание что у вас расписание разное. Я же предположил что расписание на неделю тоже самое что и на семестр, отличается только количеством выводимых дней.

Comment: Ладно, тогда возникает проблема.Первая: мне придется выполнить сразу все запросы, даже те, которые находятся на странице ViewPager, которую я возможно даже не открою (а запрос я уже выполнил и не один).
Вторая проблема: Например есть во Fragment метод showSemesters(). Как мне писать логику, если она используется в 2 из 3 листах ViewPager(на неделю и на семестр; на день не используется). Для демонстрации можете посмотреть https://lk.ugatu.su/raspisanie/#timetable

Comment: Не забывайте, если вы делаете через фрагменты и ViewPager то ViewPager будет создавать соседние с видимым элементом то есть те же фрагменты будут выполнять ту же самую пачку запросов. Как то разницы между "за семестр" и "за неделю" я не заметил... По сути это один и тот же объект с одним и тем же представлением, отличающийся похоже только запросом. На дату я вообще не нашел расписание. Я не говорю что моя реализация лучше, я вам дал удочку, а использовать мою или свою, решать вам.

Comment: Оффтоп, но вы неправильно работаете с Moxy. Явно передавать View в Presenter не нужно (более того, это ломает весь профит от этой библиотеки).

Comment: @post_zeew и как по вашему? вызывать в presenter 
  getViewState()?

Comment: @danilshik, Да, именно так.

Comment: @Valeriy ваш комментарий верен только при количество вкладок не более 3 (хранит по одному слева и справа), если больше, то нет

Comment: А у вас их будет больше?

Comment: @Valeriy нет, я просто уточнил, вдруг кто-то через какое-то время прочтет

Comment: @Valeriy, у меня имеется spinner семестр? который встречается на двух layout. Мне получается нужно делать 2 разных Spinner, так как я не могу один одновременно искать и на 1 Layout и на 2 Layout? Получается 2 запроса уйдут